# Plotting likert scales with plot_likert function from sjPlot

Tags: r, plot, sjplot, likert

I have likert scale data in character format and want to plot it using `plot_likert` function from `sjPlot` `R` package.

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(
  matrix(
    data = sample(x = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), size = 500, replace = TRUE),
    ncol = 5
    )
  )
    
head(df1)
                 X1                X2                X3                X4
1           Neutral           Neutral Strongly Disagree    Strongly Agree
2          Disagree          Disagree    Strongly Agree             Agree
3           Neutral    Strongly Agree Strongly Disagree             Agree
4           Neutral    Strongly Agree             Agree Strongly Disagree
5           Neutral           Neutral          Disagree Strongly Disagree
6 Strongly Disagree Strongly Disagree             Agree Strongly Disagree
                 X5
1          Disagree
2 Strongly Disagree
3 Strongly Disagree
4           Neutral
5 Strongly Disagree
6             Agree

library(sjPlot)

plot_likert(df1)

    Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a character to a double
In addition: There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

However, `plot_likert` works for numeric data.

```
df2 <-
  data.frame(
  matrix(
    data = sample(x = 1:5, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
    ncol = 5
    )
  )

df2

plot_likert(df2)
```

An help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot your data you have to convert your `character`s to `ordered factor`s before passing it to `plot_likert`. Otherwise, how should `plot_likert` know, how to order your categories.

Additionally note that `plot_likert` works only for an even number of categories (see `?plot_likert`). But you you set a neutral category via option  `cat.neutral`.

```r
library(sjPlot)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    matrix(
      data = sample(x = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), size = 500, replace = TRUE),
      ncol = 5
    )
  )

df1 <- dplyr::mutate_all(df1, ~ ordered(., levels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")))

plot_likert(df1, cat.neutral = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan for very useful answer.